# Visual Studio 2013 remote debugging

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1, remote-debugging, windows-rt

I own a Surface RT and I was programming in Visual Studio 2013.
I found the tutorial online on how to set it up but I couldn't do it. Right by the part Visual Studio tries to find remote connections it doesn't find the surface. If I reboot the surface, right about when I open  the remote debugger there is a small (10 seconds) period where it becomes available on my Visual Studio to select but it disappears right after never giving me the change to remote debug the app.

Does anyone had this problem before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the Surface's address manually.

Right-click your Windows 8 project, select Properties, go to Debug tab. Here select Target device: Remote Machine and then in Remote machin field enter the address and port your Surface shows you when you run the Remote Debugging Monitor (in the very first message you will see something like `Msvsmon started a new server named 'SOMEADDRESS:PORT'. Waiting for new connections.`). This usually helps when Visual Studio fails to find the device on it's own.

Comment: I'll try that as soon as I get home. 
I'll let you know how it went. Thanks!